# How do I retrieve HTML dynamically generated from an aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

To be specific, here is what I am doing, and here is what I am trying to do:

I'm coding an ASP.NET page, with VB code behind. When the user clicks a button on the page, I send them an email with information and instructions. Rather than sending a plain text email, I send a nice, pretty, HTML-formatted one. Right now, I'm doing this in a way that I KNOW will be difficult to maintain. That is, I'm straight up writing out all of the html. i.e.

```
    markup += "<fieldset>"

    markup += "<legend>"
    markup += "Required Documents"
    markup += "</legend>"
```

...and so on. Is there a way to create an aspx page (with vb code behind), and send the html of that page in the body of the email? The information is dynamic, so this pseudo-page would need logic in the on-load event to format the html correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Ryan, I know that's not an answer to your question but I would recommend to use StringBulder instead of concatenation of string values. 

Dim sb as new StringBulder
sb.append("<fieldset>")
sb.append("<legend>")
'and so on

return sb.ToString

The reason is StringBuilder is faster.

Comment: I actually did it that way at first, but felt that it was more confusing to look at. For the size of the webpage (maybe 40-50 lines of HTML) speed isn't too big of an issue...but I appreciate your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string html = client.DownloadString("http://domain.com/emailtemplate.aspx?id=1");
```

Comment: This pulled the straight ASP code...didn't go through the HTML generation part.

Comment: Wow. that is surprising. I will have to take a look at that. I would have figured that the web server would treat it like a normal http request.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a database you can always drop the html in there otherwise, I solved this problem by creating a mailtemplate.html file with [replace] sections in it so all you have to do is read the file into a string object do your replaces and then send it out.
 If you have to you can maintain multiple templates this way. I use it mostly as a wrapper on emails my systems need to send out so my template has a [body] tag in it that gets replaced with whatever message I need to send. I have also used this method to wrap multiple files into a single email output.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to build the html on the fly... One (certainly the most maintainable) solution is to build a template based system.

Technically you maintain your html (e.g. email shots) in a directory read the templates from your ASP.NET program, fill in the details and send the html mail to the user.